# Delete all row in a table where all content are equals to NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-delete

Based in a table with follow structure:

column1   column2   column3   ...   columnN

1         null      null      null  null

How i can delete all the row in the table that contain all null values? (except the 1st column that is an ID column)

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE COALESCE (column2,column3,column4) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Please use the below code:

`Delete from tbl1 where ISNULL(column1,'')=''
and ISNULL(column2,'')='' and ISNULL(column3,'')=''`